# What is .d-grid class in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working with block buttons with bootstrap `v5.1` and I used  `d-grid` to make my buttons responsive.

```
    <div class="d-grid ">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
</div>
```

I wanted to know what `d-grid` here does, as i could not find any documentation regarding this.

Comment: It's similar to `display: grid;`. You can always check what a class does by checking its CSS properties in the inspector (via a browser). https://bootstrapshuffle.com/classes/display/d-grid

Comment: So 'd-grid' adds the CSS property 'display: grid' to it, right?

Comment: Yes thats correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The d- part of the class is part of the display utility class. This generally changes the value of the CSS display property: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

In your example, the d-grid class is making the div element become a grid container which is part of the CSS Grid Layout. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

It looks like the "grid" value is not supported by Bootstrap 5 and it is an old legacy value for CSS. That should be changed to one of the following values:

```
none
inline
inline-block
block
table
table-cell
table-row
flex
inline-flex
```

Comment: `grid` is absolutely NOT legacy. It's one of the most recent css display tech.
That's why Bootstrap 5 **added** `d-grid` to its `utilities`, while it was totally lacking in Bootstrap 4
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/migration/#utilities    

```
Added .d-grid to display utilities and new gap utilities (.gap) for CSS Grid and flexbox layouts.
```

Answer (score 9):

"D-" is kind of utilities for Bootstrap that effect on Display directly and help you to have Grid Layout. In Css we call that "Display".

**How it works** :

```
.d-{value}
```

**example :**

```
CSS: display: inline-flex;
Bootstrap: d-inline-flex
```

**All of values**

*none

inline

inline-block

block

table

table-cell

table-row

flex

inline-flex*

**ABOUT GRID :**

CSS Grid Layout excels at dividing a page into major regions or defining the relationship in terms of size, position, and layer, between parts of a control built from HTML primitives.

Like tables, grid layout enables an author to align elements into columns and rows. However, many more layouts are either possible or easier with CSS grid than they were with tables. For example, a grid container's child elements could position themselves so they actually overlap and layer, similar to CSS positioned elements.
sources for more information :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid_display_grid